# Help Identifiing This Bonsai

Tags: identification, bonsai

So today was my 12yr anniversary at work. The owner of the company knew I was looking to try my hand at growing a bonsai. So when I came into the office this morning this guy was on my desk.

He didn't ask what species it was when he bought it. SoI've been looking at pictures for the better part of the day trying to identify it. I think it might be a Serissa Foetida Mount Fuji, but not sure. So hoping someone else can verify or correct my guess.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The growth habit doesn't look right for Serissa Foetida. From the way it's growing, I would take a guess that it's a variegated-leaf Cotoneaster.